# How do I enable "look up/down" in the dialog mode?

Tags: virtual-battlespace

I'm developing scenario in the Virtual Battlespace 2 Virtual Tool Kit. In my scenario I need to use dialog mode for satisfying some requirements. I've successfully created dialog, and I need movement in the dialog, so that is also done.

The problem is that, if the player gets shot by a terrorist in the scenario, then the player body reacts to that impact. This causes the player head to lock in the upward and downward direction. From this position, the player can no longer look up or down. I need to close the dialog, reset ther player position and start the dialog, again.

How do I enable "look up/down" in the dialog mode?

Comment: Never heard about VBS2 VTK (googled it now), maybe you have more luck asking VBS2 development team directly? They sure will support their customers.